# C++ Polymorphism and the new keyword

Tags: c++, pointers, polymorphism

Is there some way to allocate memory depending on the type of pointer passed?

Here is my problem: I have a 'bouncyball' and 'hero' class both inheriting from 'Actor'. To add a bouncyball, I call:

```
_actors.push_back(new Bouncyball());
```

For a hero, it would be:

```
_actors.push_back(new Hero());
```

Since _actors is a vector of Actor pointers, it works because of polymorphism. But I want to write a generic method to add new actors to my scene:

```
unsigned Scene::addActor(Actor * actor){
    this->_actors.push_back(new [something]);
}
```

Because the parameter can be any derivative of Actor, I don't know what to allocate memory for... I can work around this with a case statement, but what if I derive other Actors later on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is wrong with this:

```
unsigned Scene::addActor(Actor * actor){
    this->_actors.push_back(actor);
    //what do you want to return? why not make return type as void?
}
```

Isn't it `actor` which you want to add to `_actors`?

And you can call `addActor()` as:

```
scene.addActor(new Bouncyball());
scene.addActor(new Hero());
```

Make sure that you declare the destructor of `Actor` as `virtual`, as most likely you would want to delete derived class objects through the pointer of base type (which is `Actor`).

Comment: I return the index of the created actor in my actual code. This solution is beautifully simple :) Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Nawaz's solution is fine, but an alternative is a template member function:

```
template<typename T>
unsigned Scene::addActor()
{
   _actors.push_back(new T());
}
```

And then in the client code:

```
scene.addActor<Hero>();
```

It's worth noting that the template member function will need to be implemented in a header or file included by a header (such as a .inl). If you implement it directly in the class body you shouldn't write Scene:: in front of addActor().

One advantage of this method is that clients are not calling new. It's generally 'bad' if code is calling new, but isn't calling delete, and in this case delete would presumably be called by the Scene class later. This also creates a pinch point if a custom allocator needs to be used for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a pv class `Clonable`:

```
template <typename T>
struct Clonable {
    virtual smart_ptr<T> clone() const = 0;
}
```

for `smart_ptr` being `std::shared_ptr`, `std::unique_ptr`, `boost::shared_ptr`, etc.
The point is to refcount the pointer to avoid use of manual `delete`s, except when writing a custom `Deleter`.

Then define `Actor` as:

```
 class Actor : ..., public Clonable<Actor> {
 ...
 public:
     ...
     virtual smart_ptr<T> clone() const { return 0; }
     ...
 ...
}
```

Then, for `T : public Actor`,

`scene.addActor((T()).clone());`